# Compare two objects based on property names

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to compare two JS Objects based on their properties no matter the values ?

For example :

```js
var first = {
    a: 2,
    b: 3
}
var second = {
   a: 4,
   b: 5
}
console.log(first.hasPropertiesOf(second)); //true
```

Comment: If you knew how to enumerate all of an object's properties, would you still need help in solving this problem?

Comment: Object.keys(first).every(elem => Object.keys(second).includes(elem)) && Object.keys(second).every(elem => Object.keys(first).includes(elem))

Comment: Hacky solution: `JSON.stringify(Object.keys(first)) == JSON.stringify(Object.keys(second))`